# Proving injection and surjection with functions $F:C^B\to C^A$, $F(f)=f\circ\varphi$, $\varphi: A\to B$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic

> Let $\varphi: A\to B$ and define $F:C^B\to C^A$ such that $F(f)=f\circ\varphi$. Prove the following:
>
> 1. if $\varphi$ is surjective then $F$ is injective.
> 2. if $\varphi$ is injective then $F$ is surjective.

For both of them I realize that I should begin with assuming the condition on $\varphi$ is true and the condition for $F$ is false and then apply the composition in some way to get a contradiction but I have no idea how to begin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Let $\varphi$ be surjective. Let $f_1, f_2$ be such that $F(f_1) = F(f_2).$ Now $f_1 \
\circ \varphi = f_2 \circ \varphi.$ Then $f_1 (\varphi (x)) =f_2( \varphi(x)), \forall x \in A.$ Since $\phi$ is surjective, $f_1(y) = f_2(y), \forall y \in B.$ So $f_1 =f_2.$

(2) Let $\varphi$ is injective. Let $f: A \to C$ is given. Define $g : B \to C$ by $g(y)= f( \varphi ^{-1}(y)),$ if $y \in \varphi(A)$ and $g(y) = c,$ if $y \in B \setminus \varphi (A)$ where $c \in C$ is any element. Since $\varphi$ is injective, this map is well defined. Then $g (\varphi (x)) = f(\varphi^{-1}(\varphi (x))) = f(x), \forall x \in A,$ showing that $F(g) = g\circ\varphi = f.$ Hence $F$ is surjective.

$\bf Note:$ The above given solutions are based on the assumption that all the sets $A, B, C$ are non-empty (though it was not stated in the question). In fact, if we don't assume this condition, then (2) is not true. Thanks to *Marc van Leeuwen* for pointing this. See his comment below for an example.

Comment: Thanks. 1. looks pretty straight forward now... Can you share what was your thought process for 2 please? How did you know to define $f,g$, and  $g(y)=f(\varphi^{-1}(y)), g(y)=c$? I just really doubt I could've come up with this on my own.

Comment: if $\phi$ were given bijective, then every $y \in B$ has a unique preimage $\phi^{-1}(y) \in A.$ so from the condition $g(\phi(x)) = f(x), \forall x \in A$ it's very natural choice to define $g(y) := f(\phi^{-1}(y)), \forall y \in B.$ here $\phi$ *not* bijective, but it is injective. so $\phi: A \to \phi(A)$ is bijective. you might be interested in the following link also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095468/contruction-of-bijection-between-set-of-functions

Comment: I'll check it out. Also, how is it that you don't use $F$ in 2?

Comment: $F(g) = f \Leftrightarrow g \phi = f \Leftrightarrow g(\phi(x)) = f(x), \forall x \in A.$ I showed the last equality.(And being lazy, didn't write it completely. Now added.)

Comment: The proof shows that point 2. actually fails, in one type of case: $A=C=\emptyset$ and $B\neq\emptyset$. The $f$ is vacuously injective, but $F:\emptyset^B\to\emptyset^\emptyset$ cannot be surjective, since its domain is empty while its codomain has one element.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Thank you for pointing this. I didn't think about this case. I assumed (back in my head) that all the given sets are *non-empty.* I'll add that hypothesis in my answer with due reference.